# F-16: MAIN PWR ticking sound, what is it?

Tags: cockpit, noise, f-16

What is that sound that starts when MAIN PWR switch is turned on in the F-16? Its sorta like a fast ticking sound.
Why is it there, what makes it, when does it stop? And is it also there when only putting switch to BATT?

You can hear it here:

Comment: Sounds like the vibrator in an altimeter, but I'm not an F-16 pilot, so I'll leave this guess as a comment rather than an answer.